# Grails 3 - prevent unnecessary select statements after controller exits

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Please excuse the contrived example. I just can't figure out why these selects are happening.

Domain objects:

```
class Author {
    String name
    Location location

    static mapping = {
        location lazy: true //this is default, but set here to reduce confusion
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

...

```
class Location {
    String address
    static hasOne = [longLat : LongLat]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

...

```
class LongLat {
    String longitude
    String latitude

    static belongsTo = [location:Location]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

...

Bootstrap init:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
        Location loc = new Location(address: '123 asdf dr', longLat: new LongLat(longitude: 0.5, latitude: 0.5)).save(flush:true)
        new Author(name: 'Author Name', location: loc).save(flush:true)
    }
```

...

Action from controller:

```
def index() {
    println "Start Controller"
    Author.get(1)
    render '1'
    println "End Controller"
}
```

I have logging turned on:

```
logSql: true
formatSql: true
```

The output:

```
Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development
Start Controller
Hibernate:
    select
        this_.id as id1_0_0_,
        this_.version as version2_0_0_,
        this_.location_id as location3_0_0_,
        this_.name as name4_0_0_
    from
        author this_
    where
        this_.id = ?
End Controller
Hibernate:
    select
        location0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        location0_.version as version2_1_0_,
        location0_.address as address3_1_0_
    from
        location location0_
    where
        location0_.id=?
Hibernate:
    select
        longlat0_.id as id1_2_0_,
        longlat0_.version as version2_2_0_,
        longlat0_.latitude as latitude3_2_0_,
        longlat0_.location_id as location4_2_0_,
        longlat0_.longitude as longitud5_2_0_
    from
        long_lat longlat0_
    where
        longlat0_.location_id=?
```

Why are these last two selects happening, and how can I stop them without resorting to HQL?

I'm using Grails 3.2.3.

Comment: Is the view you are displaying looking at the `location` property of your `Author` object? If so then this is lazy fetching the association when anything other than the `id` is being referenced. You might want to include your view code too so we can better assist you.

Comment: I'm not rendering a Grails View, just '1'. It's not due to the view calling a proxy domain object.

Comment: Perhaps then it's fetching the association for the Hibernate cache. Have you tried forcing lazy loading on the domain class association (mappings I see to recall).

Comment: Yes, I have. I'll edit the original post to reduce confusion with the lazy loading.

Comment: Two other things to try. How about using `load()` instead of `get()`, also try adding `discard()` on your instance after you `get()` it.

Comment: discard() does the trick, thanks! Any idea why it was happening?

Comment: OSIV and dirty checking would be my first thought ;)

Comment: Well, it solved my issue. Feel free to post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per our conversation in comments it's turned out to most likely be related to the OSIV (open session in view). The solution is to use `.discard()` to ensure that hibernate won't check to see if anything has changed (e.g. dirty checking) and needs to be persisted.